# Not able to initialise Vault

Tags: initialization, file-permissions, hashicorp-vault

I am trying to initilaise vault with below configurations

vault.hcl

```
path "*"{
    capabilities = [ "read", "list", "update","create" ]
}
```

vault.conf

```
backend "file" {
  path = "/vault/vaultsecrets"
}

listener "tcp" {
  address = "0.0.0.0:8200"
  tls_disable = 1
  tls_cert_file = "/vault/certs/host.pem"
  tls_key_file = "/vault/certs/host.key"
  tls_cipher_suites = "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA"
  tls_prefer_server_cipher_suites = "true"

}

disable_mlock = "true"
```

and it gives me following error

```
{'errors': ['failed to initialize barrier: failed to persist keyring: mkdir /vault/vaultsecrets/core: permission denied']}
```

I feel this something to do with file permissions but not sure where to change it.

**Note:works fines with vault:1.0.1 but throws the above error when I migrate to vault:1.4.3**

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are the filesystem permissions of the directory `/vault/vaultsecrets`, and what user are you running Vault with?

Comment: i am not running it as root, we have a separate user created and it has 775 permission

Comment: And which user/group owns the directory?

Comment: we have two different users 100 and 1000.vault is running with 100 user and 1000 user owns the directory.

Comment: Well that's your problem right there

Comment: ok.shall i change the permission to 777?

Comment: No, just set the `/vault/` directory and everything within it to be owned by the 100 user, and it should all work

Comment: that's not possible since we have two different pods(common(1000) and vault(100)).
common pod is a python vault client which connects to vault pod and does the rest of things like initialising ,unsealing, setting secrets etc..
so,on changing the permission to 777 it started working..

Comment: It doesn't sound like the common pod needs to have any access to the `/vault/` directory, it should communicate with Vault via its API. I don't recommend having full world-writable permissions on your Vault storage directory

Comment: ok..will change it..thanks for your response..have a good day.